# Swap positions of the first appearance of letter 'a' with the last appearance of letter 'o' Java

Tags: java

The task is asking me to make from the String, for example  "aaligatoor",
output like: "oaligatoar"
I found a solution like:

```
public static String letterReplacement(final String word) {
            String o = "o";
            String a = "a";
            if (word.contains("a") && word.contains("o")) {
                return word.replaceFirst("a", "o")
                           .replaceFirst("(?s)(.*)" + 'o', "$1" + 'a');
            } else {
                return "Your word does not contain both of 'a' and 'o' letters, sorry...";
            }
        }
```

but it looks tricky, maybe someone knows any more understandable ways to solve this? 
I appreciate your assistance and attention very much.

Comment: What is supposed to happen if there is either no 'o' or no 'a' in the input?

Comment: what have you tried so far? Show us your work. SO is not the place to get your homework done from others. Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, verifiable piece of code] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that others can run and help with the errors.

Comment: @Oli `if (word.contains("a") && word.contains("o")) {
            return word.replaceFirst("a", "o").replaceFirst("(?s)(.*)" + o, "$1" + a);
        } else {
            return "Your word does not contain both of 'a' and 'o' letters, sorry...";
        }`

Comment: @kbr sorry about that, I'll do next time better

Comment: I think that you should try to find an answer by yourself and then post it here so that people can give you their thoughts. One simple way to tackle your problem would be to use `indexOf('a')` and `lastIndexOf('o')`.

Comment: @Oli thank you sir! Task was solved, but I am also interested and curious in variety of ways of solving the task for keeping that in mind for future

Comment: Just a small hint: you should consider throwing an exception in the else-path, since otherwise you cannot easily decide whether swapping was successful or not. In both cases it returns a string, but the else case provides no solution to your task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find the first index of the "a" (`String.indexOf()`) and the last index of "o" (`String.lastIndexOf()`).  If both indexes are > -1 then swap the letters

Something like:

```
public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "aaligatoor";

        int firstAindex = data.indexOf("a");
        int lastOindex = data.lastIndexOf("o");

        if (firstAindex > -1 && lastOindex > -1) {
            char[] letters = data.toCharArray();
            letters[firstAindex] = 'o';
            letters[lastOindex] = 'a';

            data = new String(letters);
        }
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

Result

```
oaligatoar
```

Comment: Your code behaves differently from the initial solution. In your code `oa` will be swapped to `ao`, whereas the initial solution preserves `oa`. Don't know whether this is on purpose, though. If you take the task in the headline literally then I would say your solution is right - if  `a` needs to be before `o` in the string, it's not :)

Answer (score 5):

```
String s = "aalligatoor";
int oIndex = s.lastIndexOf('o');
int aIndex = s.indexOf('a');
if (oIndex > -1 && aIndex > -1) {
   char[] stringArray = s.toCharArray();
   stringArray[oIndex] = 'a';
   stringArray[aIndex] = 'o';
   s = new String(stringArray);
   System.out.println(s);
}
```

Should be ok space and time wise. And it is fairly easy to follow and understand.

The `indexOf` methods return -1 if the letter is not found in the string. So we can check for that, and just assign the letters to the positions in the `char` array. Remember, strings in Java are immutable, so we can't assign the new positions to our original string.

Finally, we can just turn the `char` array back into the swapped string.

Comment: Good catch. I forgot to negate that when I switched my code.

Comment: This isn't any different than Shar1er80's answer that was posted 1 minute before you.

Comment: That's because we were working on it at the same time and I had not refreshed the page before he posted, so I didn't see it until I posted mine.

Comment: Awesome, very easy to understand! Thanks sir.

Comment: And yeah, I believe 1 minute is not enough to steal someone's else solution and  also change names of variables, if you are not a flash or "Prince of Persia"

Answer (score 3):

Here's the simplest method I can come up with.

```
public String swapAO(String s) {
    int a = s.indexOf('a');
    int o = s.lastIndexOf('o');
    if (a < 1 || o < 1) return s;
    String beforeA = s.substring(0, a);
    String between = s.substring(a + 1, o);
    String afterO = s.substring(o + 1);
    return beforeA + 'o' + between + 'a' + afterO;
}
```

Simply put, `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` return the first/last positions of a character, or a negative number if the character is not present. The code says, "Find the first `'a'` and last `'o'`, then take the parts of the string before the 'a'`, between the`'a'`and`'o'`, and after the`'o'`, and join them back together with the`'a'`and`'o'` switched".

N.B.: `substring(from, to)` returns the part of the string starting from `from` and stopping *before* `to` i.e. `from` is inclusive, `to` is not. Also, using `substring` is more efficient than converting to a `char[]` then back to a `String` because `substring` does not copy text from the original string, but uses the same character array as the original string internally.

You can also use Regex if you want.

```
public String swapAO(String s) {
    return s.replaceFirst("^([^a]*)a(.*)o([^o]*)$", "$1o$2a$3")
}
```

Comment: You are correct @Leo Aso `word.replaceFirst("^([^a]*)a(.*)o([^o]*)$", "$1o$2a$3")` your suggest is nice, I removed my answer to let you put it in your answer It will be helpful +1 as well

Comment: Great answer! Thanks, sir.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using pure regex:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ReplaceFirstByLastPattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(swapAByO("aaligatoor"));
    }

    public static String swapAByO(String input){

        //Pattern when a falls before o
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(a)(.*)(o)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if(matcher.find()){
            return matcher.replaceAll("$3$2$1");
        }

        //Pattern when o falls before a
        pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)(o)(.*?)(a)");
        matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if(matcher.find()){
            return matcher.replaceAll("$1$4$3$2");
        }

        return input;
    }
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks, sir.

Comment: Your welcome. Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers.

Comment: Done, sir. I can't post questions anymore.. Could you up-vote my questions please?